# How To Concat values in view to href

Tags: angularjs

I can set a variable in my controller and assign it to an href like this:

```
<a ng-href="{{myVar}}" >x</a>
```

But I can't figure out how to prefix it in my view.  The following does not give my the myVar

```
<a ng-href="http://{{myVar}}" >x</a>
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: are you sure angularJs does work in your project ? that might seems dumb, but i don't see anything wrong in what you pasted

Comment: this should work. Are you sure you have access to myVar in your view?

Comment: Yeah, you are following the correct syntax according to the [documentation for `ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).  It's probably a `$scope` issue.

Comment: Can you include the controller code too?

Comment: you could need to use `$sce.trustedResourceUrl`, are you seeing any error in console? Or you want to decide the protocol it should be `http`/`https`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Try

<a ng-href="{{'http://' + myVar}}">x</a>
```

Comment: but the above thing should also work,,this is the only improved way

Comment: OP should have missed something or the problem might be different